# How to include gradient color in the edges of a force-directed graph using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed, force-directed-graph

As a beginner I am having problem in including the gradient color in edges of a force directed graph.

**Here I have added the color to all the nodes and links through style tag**

```
<style>
    .node{
        fill: blue;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .link{
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>
```

This results in coloring of all edges in black...
And I want to add the gradient color to the edges..
Similar to the image shared below

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .node{
        fill: blue;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .link{
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var width = 640,
            height = 480;

        var links = [
            {source: 'Rohit', target: 'Deep'},
            {source: 'Deep', target: 'Deepa'},
            {source: 'Deepa', target: 'Rohit'},
        ];
        var nodes = {};

        //adding to nodes
        links.forEach(function(link){
            link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
                (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});

            link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
                (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

        //adding svg to body

        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([width, height])
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .linkDistance(300)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
            .data(links)
            .enter().append('line')
            .attr('class', 'link');

        var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('r', width*0.003);

        //define the tick func.
        function tick(e){
            node
                .attr('cx', function(d){
                return d.x;
                })
                .attr('cy', function(d){
                    return d.y;
                })
                .call(force.drag);
            
            link
                .attr('x1', function(d){
                return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr('y1', function(d){
                return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr('x2', function(d){
                return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr('y2', function(d){
                return d.target.y;
                })

        }


    </script>
</body>
```

**Here is the full script**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients). For the future, and any styling needs you might have, just check the MDN docs with the SVG youre working with. In most cases it is less of a 'can D3 style a certain way' and more of a 'can SVGs be styled this way'.

The `var defs = svg.append('defs');` is appending a [defs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs) block to the DOM. This is used to "store graphical objects that will be used at a later time", in our case, it will be a `<linearGradient/>` that will be used later (on our line).

The `var gradient = defs .append('linearGradient')`  is where we define our gradient, where it starts, and its beginning and end colors. As with a [line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) we can add the `x1`,`x2`,`y1`, and `y2` to detail the starting endpoint of the line both on the x axis and y axis. When using percentages, you can define the start and end points of the gradient. If you play around and use

```
          .attr('x1', '0%')
          .attr('x2', '0%')
          .attr('y1', '90%')
          .attr('y2', '100%');
```

you can observe most of the line being solid red with very little ease into the blue. Although the same effect could be achieved using the `stop` `offsets`.

The `.append('stop')` is where we actually define the start and end colors, and how much of the line they take up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .node{
        fill: blue;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .link{
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var width = 640,
            height = 480;

        var links = [
            {source: 'Rohit', target: 'Deep'},
            {source: 'Deep', target: 'Deepa'},
            {source: 'Deepa', target: 'Rohit'},
        ];
        var nodes = {};

        //adding to nodes
        links.forEach(function(link){
            link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
                (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});

            link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
                (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

        //adding svg to body

        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        var defs = svg.append('defs');

        var gradient = defs
          .append('linearGradient')
          .attr('id', 'svgGradient')

        gradient
          .append('stop')
          .attr('class', 'start')
          .attr('offset', '0%')
          .attr('stop-color', 'red')
          .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

        gradient
          .append('stop')
          .attr('class', 'end')
          .attr('offset', '100%')
          .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
          .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([width, height])
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .linkDistance(300)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
            .data(links)
            .enter().append('line')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .attr('stroke', 'url(#svgGradient)');

        var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('r', width*0.003);

        //define the tick func.
        function tick(e){
            node
                .attr('cx', function(d){
                return d.x;
                })
                .attr('cy', function(d){
                    return d.y;
                })
                .call(force.drag);
            
            link
                .attr('x1', function(d){
                return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr('y1', function(d){
                return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr('x2', function(d){
                return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr('y2', function(d){
                return d.target.y;
                })

        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does the line                                                                               
           ''' var gradient = defs
          .append('linearGradient')
          .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
          .attr('x1', '0%')
          .attr('x2', '100%')
          .attr('y1', '0%')
          .attr('y2', '100%');'''                                                                                                     
            used

Comment: I simplified the answer, the x1-y2 attributes were not actually needed, but I explained their purpose still.

Comment: No actually what did you mean by the x1-y2 co-ordinates that I didn't understand

Comment: They are used to draw lines in this case. The x1 is where the line **begins** on the x axis, x2 is where the line **ends** on the x axis, and the same applies to the y's. Check the [line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) docs to read more.

Comment: Look at your `tick()` function. To understand lets just say the simulation runs for 100 "ticks". You are saying, for every tick of the simulation, ` .attr('x1', function(d){return d.source.x;})` which is setting the `x1` attribute (the line's starting point on the x axis) to match the x position of the source node its attached to, and then we attach the `x2` (lines end point on the x axis) to the x coordinate of the target node.

Comment: @SyedJafri Thanks for the really great answer. Could you please explain these lines of the code as well  gradient
          .append('stop')
          .attr('class', 'start')
          .attr('offset', '0%')
          .attr('stop-color', 'red')
          .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

        gradient
          .append('stop')
          .attr('class', 'end')
          .attr('offset', '100%')
          .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
          .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

Comment: As I described in my answer you can always just consult the MDN docs. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/stop) the `stop`s  are what defines the colors of the gradient. For example, if you add an additional `stop` and adjust the `offset` to work in thirds, you could add a third color to your gradient.